# Objective-C: Flip page automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, flip

I use `Page-Based Application` in my project. 
I have pageViewController with `spineLocationMid` and iPhone with landscape orientation. How can I automatically flip page after time interval?

Answer (score 0):

Can You give the sample code  what have you tried?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13245639)

Comment: Okay.. thanks .. I will definitely do it from next time.